# Can I move buildings from a snowy super-flat map into a plains super flat map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can I move all my buildings in a world that is a snowy super-flat, into a plain super flat?

I assume I would need to know where my building files are or, the files that contain the biome so I can just change that.

Is this possible?

Comment: I assume you're asking where your `.minecraft` folder is, containing the world folders? That depends on your setup, like operating system, launcher profiles, etc.

Comment: Hi Ender, your question sounded a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179041). I've taken a stab at rewording it for you, but if that isn't to your liking you can always Edit it yourself or rollback to an earlier revision from the [revisions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/362506/revisions) page. :-)

Comment: i mean by in no addones or tools just files

Answer (score 1):

The files are in `%AppData%\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\[world name]\region` but it won't help you, because the game doesn't distinguish what is a block of the originally generated snowed over grass, and what is a block of your house you had placed. These files contain 512x512 blocks (x256 height)  areas of the world each, and they don't distinguish what was naturally generated and what was placed by the player, they also contain the biome information, so even if you 'transplant' the area with your buildings to your new world, you'll have a 512x512 area with snowfall where everywhere else it's raining.

If the structures aren't very big and there's not a lot of them, I'd recommend using the [Structure Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block). One block can save a 32x32x32 volume you can then restore elsewhere using Structure Block in 'load' mode. There are techniques of chaining more structure blocks together (essentially, save the prior structure block within the next one), so a build of 100x100 blocks or so is relatively doable. If you need more, you'll need tools like [WorldEdit](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/worldedit) - and it would probably be easier to change the biome of your world with it.